# Django: Can I create a QueryDict from a dictionary?

Tags: python, django

Imagine that I have a dictionary in my Django application:

```
dict = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', }
```

Now I want to easily create an urlencoded list of GET parameters from this dictionary. Of course I could loop through the dictionary, urlencode keys and values and then concatenate the string by myself, but there must be an easier way. I would like to use a QueryDict instance. QueryDict is a subclass of dict, so it should be possible somehow.

```
qdict = QueryDict(dict) # this does not actually work
print qdict.urlencode()
```

How would I make the second to last line work?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

How about?

```py
from django.http import QueryDict

ordinary_dict = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', }
query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
query_dict.update(ordinary_dict)
```

Comment: Not according to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.update

Comment: should be `qdict = QueryDict('')`, and then this indeed works. Thank you.

Comment: Thanx. Did not know the other approach. Cool.

Comment: Instead of copying, you can create a mutable QueryDict straight away: `QueryDict('', mutable=True)`

Comment: This option works incorrect with dictionary of lists. See @Arpit Singh answer.

Answer (score 24):

Python has a built in tool for encoding a dictionary (any mapping object) into a query string

```
params = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', }

urllib.urlencode(params)

'a=one&b=two'
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

`QueryDict` takes a querystring as first param of its contstructor

`def __init__(self, query_string, mutable=False, encoding=None):`

`q = QueryDict('a=1&b=2')`

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L260

Update: in **Python3**, urlencode has [moved to urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

params = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', }
urlencode(params)
'a=one&b=two'
```

Comment: m) it's so obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Your answer is what I wanted, but not the exact answer for the question. Do you mind if accept the other answer, but create a new question where you can post this answer again?

Comment: This works, but is a very inefficient round-trip to make!

Answer (score 16):

Actually a little indirect but more logical way to achieve this is using MultiValueDict.
This way multiple values per key can be stored in a QueryDict and .getlist method should then work fine.

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict, MultiValueDict
dictionary = {'my_age': ['23'], 'my_girlfriend_age': ['25', '27'], }

qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
qdict.update(MultiValueDict(dictionary))

print qdict.get('my_age')  # 23
print qdict['my_girlfriend_age']  # 27
print qdict.getlist('my_girlfriend_age')  # ['25', '27']
```

Comment: Hm..  Unlike the others, which only handle single values, this one requires value to be lists (it breaks strings into a list of characters).  Seems there's no simple way to handle both.

Answer (score 5):

My solution works both for single and multiple key values:

```
def dict_to_querydict(dictionary):
    from django.http import QueryDict
    from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict

    qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        d = {key: value}
        qdict.update(MultiValueDict(d) if isinstance(value, list) else d)

    return qdict
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't be much more late to the party, but I recently needed to do the same - but to preserve the read-only behaviour of a 'real' QueryDict from a response object.

Adapting the code from `QueryDict.fromkeys()` method gave a nice function:

```py
from django.http import QueryDict

def querydict_from_dict(data: Dict[str, Any],  mutable=False) -> QueryDict:
    """
    Return a new QueryDict with keys (may be repeated) from an iterable and
    values from value.
    """
    q = QueryDict('', mutable=True)

    for key in data:
        q.appendlist(key, data[key])

    if not mutable:
        q._mutable = False

    return q
```