# What is the difference between a QueryDict and MultiValueDict?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I was looking to convert a dict to a QueryDict in my django project. Couple of links exists to explain this ([Django: Can I create a QueryDict from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363628/django-can-i-create-a-querydict-from-a-dictionary) and [How to change a django QueryDict to Python Dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349573/how-to-change-a-django-querydict-to-python-dict)). This is my simple dictionary which I want to convert `abc = {'a': 1, 'b':[1,2,3]}`. I have tried this approach:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict
abc = { 'a': 1, 'b':[1,2,3]}
mdict = MultiValueDict(abc)
qdict = QueryDict(mdict)
```

This is the error trace I am getting

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.pyc in parse_qsl(qs, keep_blank_values, strict_parsing)
407     Returns a list, as G-d intended.
408     """
409     pairs = [s2 for s1 in qs.split('&') for s2 in s1.split(';')]
410     r = []
411     for name_value in pairs:
AttributeError: 'MultiValueDict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Why this has failed and how can I get this done?
Also what are the differences between MultiValueDict and QueryDict?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MultiValueDict` is a dictionary subclass that can handle multiple values assigned to a key.So you should pass `values` of `dict` as `list`. here,  `1->[1]`.

> In an HttpRequest object, the GET and POST attributes are instances of django.http.QueryDict, a dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple values for the same key. This is necessary because some HTML form elements, notably , pass multiple values for the same key.
>
> The QueryDicts at request.POST and request.GET will be immutable when accessed in a normal request/response cycle. To get a mutable version you need to use .copy().

Then `MultiValueDict` can be convert to `QueryDict`as

```
abc = { 'a': [1], 'b':[1,2,3]}
mdict = MultiValueDict(abc)
qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
qdict.update(mdict)
>>>QueryDict: {u'a': [1], u'b': [1, 2, 3]}>
>>>dict(qdict.iterlists())
{u'a': [1], u'b': [1, 2, 3]}
>>>qdict.getlist('b')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Are qdict.getlist('b') and mdict.getlist('b') the same?

Answer (score 4):

QueryDict is a specialized class of MultiValueDict, The only major difference between them is that, QueryDict is immutable by default.

To quote from QueryDict docstring:-

> A specialized MultiValueDict which represents a query string. A QueryDict can be used to represent GET or POST data. It subclasses
>       MultiValueDict since keys in such data can be repeated, for instance
>       in the data from a form with a  field.
>       By default QueryDicts are immutable, though the copy() method
>       will always return a mutable copy.

You can consult code itself - [QueryDict code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py)

As far as initialization of query dict from multivalue dict is concerned, QueryDict does not allow passing any dic in `__init__`. I guess, it is an oversight on their part.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of django.http.request.QueryDict:

> """
>       A specialized MultiValueDict which represents a query string.
>       A QueryDict can be used to represent GET or POST data. It subclasses
>       MultiValueDict since keys in such data can be repeated, for instance
>       in the data from a form with a  field.
>       By default QueryDicts are immutable, though the copy() method
>       will always return a mutable copy.
>       Both keys and values set on this class are converted from the given encoding
>       (DEFAULT_CHARSET by default) to unicode.
>       """

And from the definition of django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDict:

> """
>       A subclass of dictionary customized to handle multiple values for the
>       same key.
>
> > > > d = MultiValueDict({'name': ['Adrian', 'Simon'], 'position': ['Developer']})
> > > >         d['name']
> > > >             'Simon'
> > > >         d.getlist('name')
> > > >             ['Adrian', 'Simon']
> > > >         d.getlist('doesnotexist')
> > > >             []
> > > >         d.getlist('doesnotexist', ['Adrian', 'Simon'])
> > > >             ['Adrian', 'Simon']
> > > >         d.get('lastname', 'nonexistent')
> > > >             'nonexistent'
> > > >         d.setlist('lastname', ['Holovaty', 'Willison'])
> > > >             This class exists to solve the irritating problem raised by cgi.parse_qs,
> > > >             which returns a list for every key, even though most Web forms submit
> > > >             single name-value pairs.
> > > >             """

So, being a child class MultiValueDict, QueryDict has the additional property of being immutable. And this is the major point of difference.